# constrain proportions between intervals

Tags: php, rating

i'm trying to make a small class in php that would be used to integrate a rating system and i'm stuck on a little probably simple problem.
i want to show the rating between 0 and 5 but the votes can be in any interval like 1 to 10 or 1 to 12.
for example if interval was of votes was 1-12 and total score/total votes would be 6 i want to actually display 2.5
i'm currently using this

```
$rating = number_format(round(($total_score/$total_votes)*2)/2,1);
```

so how can i make this to show values only 0-5 interval ?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following your terminology. Can you give a detailed example of the scoring?

Comment: I don't get you. (Although I think that I can help you) Can you explain further?

Comment: Well, You could try taking the percentage rating and then convert that into 5ths. For example: 6/10 = .6, .6 * 5 = 3.

Comment: Note 0-5 starts at 0, 1-12 starts at 1, makes a lot of difference...

Comment: yes, say i set the votes to be from 1-12 the users votes and when i use the formula above i get 6 witch is half of the interval allowed so all i want is to commute that to 1-5 interval so 6 in this case would become 2.5

Comment: Have corrected the question, you wrote 10 but meaned 12. Now it makes sense ;) Use a simple percentage calculation -> lower school magic :D

Comment: For all purposes, 6 on a scale of 1 to 12 is 2.2727.... on a scale from 0-5. 6 on a scale from ***0*** to 12 is indeed 2.5 on the 0-5 scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fromminrate = 1;
$frommaxrate = 12;
$tominrate = 0;
$tomaxrate = 5;
$rating = $tominrate + (
     ((($total_score/$total_votes)-$fromminrate)
     / ($frommaxrate-$fromminrate))
     * ($tomaxrate-$tominrate));
```

Comment: If you keep in mind max=best, min=worst, you can even swap those around (so, a minrate of 0 = worst and a max rate of -12=best), would still translate properly.

Comment: Thank you ! this works, if you are curios this is how i used it https://github.com/ionutvmi/Rating-System/blob/master/rating_system.php

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple percentage calculation like this:

```
<?php

$number_of_votes = 10; // real votes
$max_number_of_votes = 12; // vote range
$max_display_votes = 5; // display range

$perc = $max_display_votes * $number_of_votes / $max_number_of_votes;
$display = intval(round($perc)); // optional, round and convert to int

echo $display;
```

As a voting range - by its nature - starts at zero, you don't have to worry about the lower border and can simplify your calculations. ;)

---

Explanation:

The $number_of_votes(10) are related to $max_number_of_votes(12) as the value in question ($display) is related to $max_display_votes (5). In math:

```
$number_of_votes / $max_number_of_votes == $display / $max_display_votes;
```

or in the example:

```
10 / 12 = $display / 5;
```

You can transform this term by multiplying by 5:

```
10 * 5 / 12 = $display;
```

and thats my 'formula' ;)

Comment: Thats what I understood from your question. It's really hard to understand what you try. Please enhance your question and I'll give more help. Btw you use once vote once score. What is the difference? is there a difference?